# Can you restrict Command + Tilde (CMD + ~) in El Capitan to switch between only windows on the same desktop?

Tags: window-manager, spaces, desktop, shortcut, macos

In Yosemite, I could use CMD + ~ to switch between windows of an application, but it switched only between windows on the same desktop/space. When I use the same keyboard shortcut in El Capitan, it switches to windows of the same application that are opened in other desktops. Is there a way to restrict its behavior to within the same desktop (the way it worked in Yosemite)? Thanks!

UPDATE:

As linkedlist suggested, I updated to 10.11.1, which fixed the issue when using Chrome. However, I find that PHPStorm's windows still behave as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this behavior is fixed in the new update 10.11.1. I tried it on both explorer and chrome on the same desktop and it switches to the other windows as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately, I am still seeing the same problem after updating to 10.11.1, though it does seem to be only PHPStorm that does not behave as expected. Perhaps this is a problem with only PHPStorm.